# Django let a view be seen once a time

Tags: django, session

I'm new at Django and I would like to make a view available just once per time (I think they're called sessions)

Basically, if someone request a page, the page can be access only if nobody is on that page at the same time. If someone is seeing the page and a new request of the same page come in, it should be declined

From what I've understood, sessions should help to do it but, I need for both authenticated user and not authenticated ones.

Is there a way to do that?

I'm seeing solution that limits one session per logged in user, but I need one session per page views

Comment: Define "on the same time". A webserver receives a request, and returns a response. People can then see that response and save for example the page for an arbitrary amount of time, so the server does not know if a person has left the page.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's what I'm trying to understand. There's no way to check if someone is still interactive to the page while someone else are requesting it, isn't it?

Comment: you can `trick` by call server from client. Like ping command every 10 second. By this way server know has someone use it. And you can lock page.
If nobody use in 10 second, you will release lock, and try ping again

Comment: @NgocPham: yes, but that has all problems like the [*two generals problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem). It is also perfectly possible to disable the client sending the ping, since that runs at the client side, and if something stored your data/process, it is not your data/process anymore.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How about using the user's `IP address`? I think it may solve this problem, as an IP address can be both `authenticated` and `unauthenticated`.

Comment: That is not the main problem, but even an IP address might be problematic, since for for example universities, multiple users often have the same IP address with a different port number, and one can also run two sessions on different IP addresses (like a VPN) that ultimately go to the same user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How about creating custom `SessionTimeoutMiddleware`, but that one should goes to the authenticated user only.